# DotNetNuke Azure Accelerator after install login and password not working on website

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

DotNetNuke Azure Accelerator seemed to install without any problems. I checked the log and all the events were successful.  I then tried to login but the login details I provided for the database don't seem to work. Have I missed an important step. How are the login details created and where are they located to login into the DotNetNuke site created by the DotNetNuke Azure Accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is a default username and password that comes with the auto installation. There was nothing wrong with my DotNetNuke Azure setup.